# Color one cell ncurses

Tags: c, ncurses

I wonder, is that possible to kind of "bake" one cell color using ncurses?
 I mean, i want to set one cell color and then, when i use mvprintw with some other color in attron() i want the cell to still be this "baked" color.

```
//default color
mvprintw(0, 0, my_game_board);
bake(2,4,cell_color); 
mvprintw(0, 0, my_game_board); //update game board, and then ONLY 2,4 cell should be cell_color.
```

.

Its like i want to set color for cell, not for content. (when content change, color shoud be same)

Comment: You needs to be a bit specific with tags. `C` and `C++` are different languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just using `mvpwintw`, etc., as illustrated, you cannot.  That ultimately resolves into `waddch` calls  (see [source](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/3ff1eb8118bdf68f4000dd45fd510637e290405b/ncurses/base/lib_addch.c#L57)), which pay attention to

- the window background (see [`bkgd`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_bkgd.3x.html#h3-bkgd)),
- the window attributes (see [`attr_on`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_attr.3x.html#h3-Window-attributes)) and
- the character attributes (see last paragraph in [`addch`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_addch.3x.html#h3-Adding-characters)).

You *could* use the [panel library](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/panel.3x.html) to manage the unchanging cell as a separate layer (in its own window), but probably would find it too complicated to use for multiple unchanging cells.